# Linear Transformation. Adjoint operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I found a problem while I was working out an exercise:

> If the linear transformation $A: \mathbb{R}^{m} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ that transform an orthonormal set of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ in an orthonormal set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the adjoint $A^{\ast}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is left inverse of $A$?

I'm not sure about the injectivity. Any hint? I didn't want a solution.

Comment: You mean left inverse of $A$ instead of inverse of $A$?

Comment: @KennyLau, sorry.. left inverse.

Answer (score 1):

For injectivity, note that for any non-zero vector $x$, the normalization $\hat x := \dfrac x {\|x\|}$ is well-defined. Then, the set $\{\hat x\}$ is orthonormal. What then can we say about $\{A\hat x\}$? And then $Ax$?

So, what can we say about $\ker A$?

Answer (score 1):

Pick $\{e_i\}$ an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$. The hypothesis gives you that
$$\langle Ae_i, Ae_j\rangle =\langle e_i,e_j \rangle. $$
Use this to establish that
$$\langle Av,Aw \rangle= \langle v,w \rangle $$
for any $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^m$. It then holds that
$$\langle A^*Av,w \rangle=\langle v, w \rangle$$
for all $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^m$, which should give you everything you need to conclude what you want.